# Specialized Function with Abstract Parameter in context with Generalized Function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that accepts an abstract type with a specific templated value but also have a generic function that accepts other types. As shown in my example code.

I've simplified my example code to just the necessary parts, so you can get a better idea for what I'm asking about:

```
template <typename ValTy, typename RootTy=void>
class ITransformer
{
private:
  int sz;
  ValTy* inBuffer[1000];

public:
  using SelfType = typename std::conditional<std::is_void<RootTy>::value, ITransformer<ValTy>, RootTy>::type;

  template <typename OtherRoot>
  SelfType &operator <<(const ITransformer<ValTy, OtherRoot> &other) {
    std::cout << "Used specialized operator\n";
    memcpy(&this->inBuffer[this->sz], other.inBuffer, other.size);
    this->sz += other.size;
    return *static_cast<SelfType*>(this);
  }
  // default operator, accepts all remaining types
  template <typename T>
  SelfType &operator <<(const T) {
    std::cout << "Used default operator\n";
    return *static_cast<SelfType*>(this);
  }
};

class StringTransformer : public ITransformer<char, StringTransformer>
{
public:
  StringTransformer() { }
};


int main() {
  StringTransformer() << false << (StringTransformer() << "value") << 12;
  std::cout << "End";
}
```

In the main function, I would expect the default operator to be called 3 times and the specialized one to be called once. But it never calls the specialized operator.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Active Code Example: https://repl.it/@Rhaokiel/Abstract-Parameter-in-Template

Comment: You are missing an ampersand in your default operator parameter, but it's probably not the reason this doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: That is a good observation r3mus, but it's actually as intended in my case. Not all other types are intended to be passed by reference. Unless there is some reason why that would be beneficial in this case.

Comment: I just don't see the point of passing anything by `const` value, which means always creating a copy which you can't and don't intend to modify.

Comment: Constraints let the compiler know what is likely to happen in a function so that it can better optimize. And it keeps me (the programmer) from making a critical mistake without thinking twice about it.

Also because this case is a generic function any class type, reference, or pointer could match. Otherwise, value types ignore the keyword const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `StringTransformer() << StringTransformer()`

The 2 viable overload are:

- `template <typename OtherRoot>
  SelfType &operator <<(const ITransformer<ValTy, OtherRoot> &)` (#1)
- `template <typename T> SelfType &operator <<(const T)` (#2)

(#1) requires derived to base conversion, whereas (#2) is an exact match and is so preferred.

You might usr SFINAE to (#2) to not match derived class from `ITransformer`

First, create the trait:

```
template <typename Val, typename Root>
std::true_type derived_from_ITransformer_impl(const ITransformer<Val, Root>*);
std::false_type derived_from_ITransformer_impl(...);

template <typename T>
using is_derived_from_ITransformer =
    decltype(derived_from_ITransformer_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

Then

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_derived_from_ITransformer<T>(), int> = 0>
SelfType &operator <<(const T&);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45f19d2f2918ba1f)